# convert a list of integer to a list of natural numbers

Tags: coq

I want to covert a `list of integer` to a `list of nat`. Here is the function that I return in `Coq`.

```
Fixpoint list_int_to_nat (l : list integer) : list nat :=
    match l with
      | nil => nil
      | x :: l' => let i := Z.to_nat x in
        list_int_to_nat l'
    end.
```

Could you help me to be able to translate each element of a list `integer` to a list of `nat`, because in my function I did not use the first element `i`? Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote a recursive function that always calls itself on the tail, and you do nothing with the head, so ultimately, your function with always return `nil`.

What you want here is to use the `cons` constructor from `list` to add `i` at the head of the returning list.

```
Fixpoint list_int_to_nat (l : list integer) : list nat :=
    match l with
    | nil => nil
    | x :: l' => let i := Z.to_nat x in
       i :: list_int_to_nat l'
end.
```

(Here I used the :: notation which I find more handy).

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a `map`:

```
Definition list_int_to_nat l := map Z.to_nat l.
```